# Twig if statement with ${ text }

Tags: twig

i'm trying to use this if statement:

```
{% if ${ anyNumber } <= 50 %}
    <div>Hello Number!</div>
{% endif %}
```

If i try only 'anyNumber' without ${ anyNumber } it stays empty:

```
{% if anyNumber <= 50 %}
    <div>Hello Number!</div>
{% endif %}
```

How can I do it?
Thanks

Comment: What is `${ anyNumber }`? Are you trying to call a dynamic variable in `twig`?

Comment: for example ${ shoppingcart.itemSum }